# Saving multiple records to the join table with same ids but different data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am building an E-commerce app in `cakephp3` for food and and I'm trying to save multiple records for the same `product` to the join table `orders_products` at once with different `_joinData`.

It works as expected when I save multiple products, which do not have the same id, but when I have two products with the same id it does not. For example when I try to order one caesar salad with french dressing and one caesar salad with yogurt dressing I need to save two records:

```
[
    'products' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => (int) 35,
            '_joinData' => [
                'prodcut_variation' => 'yogurt dressing',
                'product_name' => 'ceasar salad',
                'product_net_price' => (float) 1.5,
                'product_qty' => (int) 26,
                'tax_id' => (int) 2
            ]
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'id' => (int) 35,
            '_joinData' => [
                'prodcut_variation' => 'french dressing',
                'product_name' => 'ceasar salad',
                'product_net_price' => (float) 1.5,
                'product_qty' => (int) 10,
                'tax_id' => (int) 2
            ]
        ],
    ],
]
```

But cakephp will only save the first one. How can i tell cakephp to save them both?

Answer (score 0):

[Use the 'through' Option.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option)

```
<?php

class OrdersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Products', [
            'through' => 'OrdersProducts',
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('OrdersProducts');
    }
}

class ProductsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Orders', [
            'through' => 'OrdersProducts',
        ]);
    }
}

class OrdersProductsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Orders');
        $this->belongsTo('Products');
    }
}
```

And then save the Order like this:

```
[
    'orders_products' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'product_id' => (int) 35,
            'prodcut_variation' => 'yogurt dressing',
            'product_name' => 'ceasar salad',
            'product_net_price' => (float) 1.5,
            'product_qty' => (int) 26,
            'tax_id' => (int) 2
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'product_id' => (int) 35,
            'prodcut_variation' => 'french dressing',
            'product_name' => 'ceasar salad',
            'product_net_price' => (float) 1.5,
            'product_qty' => (int) 10,
            'tax_id' => (int) 2
        ],
    ]
]
```